# Tumah tahara mikva

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

If a man chalila had a mikra balaila and he didnt clean off totally and then went to the mikva and the zera hadnt dried would it make the mikva water tamei?

Answer (score 1):

The shiur is כעדשה

it would be mixed with water and בטל in the מקוה

Although one should certainly beware of בל תשקצו and wash oneself before descending. ..

Comment: so the mikva would still be metaher?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34141/759